# Selenium: Hide Command Prompt Window when starting Chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How can I hide the command prompt window that opens up along with Chromedriver when starting it? IE the black and white dialog window?

It seems there is a way to do it in the C# documentation, but I don't see anything in the Python docs.

Comment: The only way I've found to do this so far is to modify the Selenium source code where it uses `Popen` to start the service (`selenium\webdriver\common\service.py`)

Answer (score 0):

See if this will work for you (C#)

```
IWebDriver seleniumDriver;    
ChromeDriverService cService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
cService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
seleniumDriver = new ChromeDriver(cService);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First try this :**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  

var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
```

**Sometime you will still get a BLANK command prompt window :**

To fix that : 
Right click on Project and click Properties. Then change the Output type from Console Application to Windows Application.

[image]